# How to enable Google Shopping with Shopware 5.0.2?

Tags: google-shopping, shopware

I know how to do Google Shopping with a website in general.

The problem with Shopware is that the HTML file generated by Google  (`google1d9f9818967dfa4.html`) is not accessible when uploading it via FTP.

So where/how do I need to place the file in order for Google to find it?

Google needs the generated file in the root directory like:

```
example.com/google1d9f9818967dfa4.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should this file not be accessible?

Just Upload it to the Root Directory make also sure you are using the correct URL http://www.domain.com or http://domain.com